# Deep parse with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, beautifulsoup

I try to parse https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs. The idea is to extract all the drug names and some additional informationfor each drug. As you can see each webpage represents a table with drug names and the when we hit the drugname we can access to this drug information.
Let's say I will keep the following code to handle the pagination:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def drug_data():
url = 'https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/'

while url:
    print(url)
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text ,"lxml")

    #data = soup.select('name-head a')
    #for link in data:
    #    href = 'https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/' + link.get('href')
    #    pages_data(href)

    # next page url
    url = soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'page-link', 'rel': 'next'})
    print(url)
    if url:
        url = 'https://www.drugbank.ca' + url[0].get('href')
    else:
        break

  drug_data()
```

The issue is that in each page, and for each drug in the table of this page I need to capture :
Name.
Accession Number.
Structured Indications,
Generic Prescription Products,

I used the classical request/beautifusoup but can't go deep ..

Some Help please

Comment: what is a problem ? don't you know how to use `findAll()`, `find()`, `select()`, etc.  to get elements in table ? You can use `findAll` to get all `tr` and later `findAll` to find `td` in every `tr`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47912783/7698247 it might help

Comment: You might be getting stuck trying to grab the same pages. You should probably keep a queue of urls that you want to visit and/or have previously visited. Then only add urls to the queue when they have not been previously seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create function with `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` to get data from subpage

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_details(url):
    print('details:', url)

    # get subpage
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text ,"lxml")

    # get data on subpabe
    dts = soup.findAll('dt')
    dds = soup.findAll('dd')

    # display details
    for dt, dd in zip(dts, dds):
        print(dt.text)
        print(dd.text)
        print('---')

    print('---------------------------')

def drug_data():
    url = 'https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/'

    while url:
        print(url)
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text ,"lxml")

        # get links to subpages
        links = soup.select('strong a')
        for link in links:
            # exeecute function to get subpage
            get_details('https://www.drugbank.ca' + link['href'])

        # next page url
        url = soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'page-link', 'rel': 'next'})
        print(url)
        if url:
            url = 'https://www.drugbank.ca' + url[0].get('href')
        else:
            break

drug_data()
```

Comment: Thank you ... I cant run this : HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.drugbank.ca', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /drugs/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000080C8400>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10060] Une tentative de connexion a \xe9chou\xe9 car le parti connect\xe9 n\x92a pas r\xe9pondu convenablement au-del\xe0 d\x92une certaine dur\xe9e ou une connexion \xe9tablie a \xe9chou\xe9 car l\x92h\xf4te de connexion n\x92a pas r\xe9pondu',))

Comment: are you sure you have correct url ? Or maybe server blocks portal see you made many requests in short time - human can't do this. You have new problem then use button "Add Question" to create new question. You will have more place to put code and error message - and it will be more readable.

Comment: Hi Furas ! It is the server I am trying to solve this !

Comment: Hi, I can see that the code findAll, but what about the following information: https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB00639 . For example for PATENTS I want to gather patent approved date and patent number and the country which is represented by a flag !

Comment: inside `dd` you have other tags and classes so you can use more `find`, `findAll`, `select`, `select_one`, etc. to get other data. You can also use `if/else`, string functions (to check if you are in row with `Patents` - ie. `if dt.text == 'Patents': ...`) to build more complex function to get data. You can't do everthing with single `findAll`

Answer (score 0):

To crawl effectively, you'll want to implement a few measures, such as maintaining a queue of urls to visit and be aware of what urls you have already visited.

Keeping in mind that links can be absolute or relative and that redirects are very likely, you also probably want to construct the urls dynamically rather than string concatenation.

Here is a generic (we usually only want to use `example.com` on SO) crawling workflow...

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin, urlparse # python
# from urlparse import urljoin, urlparse # legacy python2
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def process_page(soup):
    '''data extraction process'''
    pass

def is_external(link, base='example.com'):
    '''determine if the link is external to base'''
    site = urlparse(link).netloc
    return base not in site

def resolve_link(current_location, href):
    '''resolves final location of a link including redirects'''
    req_loc = urljoin(current_location, href)
    response = requests.head(req_loc)
    resolved_location = response.url # location after redirects
    # if you don't want to visit external links...
    if is_external(resolved_location):
        return None
    return resolved_location

url_queue = ['https://example.com']
visited = set()
while url_queue:
    url = url_queue.pop() # removes a url from the queue and assign it to `url`
    response = requests.get(url)
    current_location = response.url # final location after redirects
    visited.add(url) # note that we've visited the given url
    visited.add(current_location) # and the final location
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    process_page(soup) # scrape the page
    link_tags = soup.find_all('a') # gather additional links
    for anchor in link_tags:
        href = anchor.get('href')
        link_location = resolve_link(current_location, href)
        if link_location and link_location not in visited:
            url_queue.append(link_location)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! what about writing the results in Pandas ? do you think this is feasable ? or I need to save the JSON format then Elasticsearch  and finally Hive ? Thanks

Comment: Should be totally possible. Just implement it in the `process_page` function. As a simple approach, you could have a pandas dataframe in the global scope that is modified in `process_page`