# How to rectify my below script to get the output side by side?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written a script in python to collect some information from a webpage. I've written it using `css selector` in a very compact manner. My script is capable of fetching the data. However, the problem I'm facing is I can't use the `css selector` in my script to get the result side by side not in serially as I've used comma separated `css selector` to fetch two types of values all at once. If I'm unable to bring the clarity, please see the below example.

The script I'm trying with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB04789")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text ,"lxml")
items = '\n'.join([item.text for item in soup.select("dl > dt , dl > dd")])
print(items)
```

Output I'm having:

```
Name
Accession Number
Type

5-methyltetrahydrofolic acid
DB04789
Small Molecule
```

Output I wish to have:

```
Name 5-methyltetrahydrofolic acid
Accession Number DB04789
Type Small Molecule
```

Is it possible to get the expected output applying some minor changes in the selector keeping it in a single line as I've tried above. Thanks for taking a look into it.

Comment: get separatelly `<dt>` (as `all_dt`) and separately `<dd>` (as `all_dd`) and use `zip(all_dt, all_dd)` to create pairs.

Comment: see code in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48116666/1832058

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your solutions. +1 for everyone. My requirement was to have any one liner solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Get separately `<dt>` (as `all_dt`) and separately `<dd>` (as `all_dd`)
and use `zip(all_dt, all_dd)` to create pairs.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB04789")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text ,"lxml")

all_dt = soup.select("dl > dt")
all_dd = soup.select("dl > dd")

for dt, dd in zip(all_dt, all_dd):
    print(dt.text, ":", dd.text)
```

You can also use `nextSibling` to get element after `dt`

```
all_dt = soup.select("dl > dt")

for dt in all_dt:
    dd = dt.nextSibling
    print(dt.text, ":", dd.text)
```

---

My full code from answer to question [Deep parse with beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48116666/1832058) which was 2 hours ago.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_details(url):
    print('details:', url)

    # get subpage
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text ,"lxml")

    # get data on subpabe
    dts = soup.findAll('dt')
    dds = soup.findAll('dd')

    # display details
    for dt, dd in zip(dts, dds):
        print(dt.text)
        print(dd.text)
        print('---')

    print('---------------------------')

def drug_data():
    url = 'https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/'

    while url:
        print(url)
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text ,"lxml")

        # get links to subpages
        links = soup.select('strong a')
        for link in links:
            # exeecute function to get subpage
            get_details('https://www.drugbank.ca' + link['href'])

        # next page url
        url = soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'page-link', 'rel': 'next'})
        print(url)
        if url:
            url = 'https://www.drugbank.ca' + url[0].get('href')
        else:
            break

drug_data()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you get the two types of data separately, you can zip them together and then print them out:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB04789")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text ,"lxml")
categories = soup.select("dl > dt")
entries = soup.select("dl > dd")
items = zip(categories, entries)

for item in items:
    print(item[0].text + ": " + item[1].text)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more or less the version of the answer I was expecting:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB04789")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text ,"lxml")
items = [': '.join([item.text,item.find_next().text]) for item in soup.select("dl > dt")]
print(items)
```